# Change States ORDER on CheckEdit Three States

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

Hy , I want to change the order of States on a `CheckEdit`
The initial order is

Unchecked  >  Checked  > Indeterminate
like in picture:

[image: Init State]

but I want the order to be like this :
Unchecked  >  Indeterminate  >  Checked

[image: Desired State]

For now I am catching `_CheckStateChanged` Event and modify the State
Do you have a better idea ?  Thanks.

Comment: I think this is wired into Windows, so the only way to do it is to override the default behavior by catching it and programmatically changing it, like you're doing. But the real question is: Why would you want to change the default, that to which users are accustomed?

Comment: I have a situation : 0 - Not Imported / Undefined - Imported / 1 - Exported (it's the client's demand)

Comment: I guess doing it the way you're doing it now is fine then, but maybe you should use another control instead of a CheckBox, like a ComboBox or something. What if an extra state is added, like emailed? It won't fit into the checkbox anymore!